# How we can use a suffix array?

Tags: arrays, suffix

I understand how the [***suffix array***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) run, but i didn't happen to see how to use it ???
Somebody can explain me the situation to use it.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on your background, how you heard about suffix arrays, and what your current understanding is?

Comment: As an example, a sorted suffix array is great for finding all occurences of a search string in a text, say if you’re working in a compression scenario.